# Excel - displaying numbers and text on cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

Hi I am struggling with a formula but not sure it can be done

In column F - I have number or text in each cell and I want to show in column G if its text to show blank and if a number show the actual number.

But in column H- I want to show the opposite so if its a number show blank and and if text show the actual text.

Can this be done - apologies if can't

Comment: Yes it can. What have you tried already?

Answer (score 4):

Beginning with row 2...

The formula for col G should be **=IF(ISNUMBER(F2),F2,"")**

The formula for col H should be **=IF(ISNUMBER(F2),"",F2)**

Once those formulas are in there, you can grab the bottom-right corner of the cursor box and drag it down the column to fill in the rest of the formulas.

[image]

Comment: @Dominic, do feel free to mark it as the answer if it helped